# How to convert logic gates to multiplexer in a circuit?

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer

In [one of my previous questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527955/which-integrated-circuit-can-i-use-instead-of-multiple-mosfet), I wanted to know what integrated circuit I could use to replace my logic gates in the circuit below:
[image: circuit with logic gates]

The [accepted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527957/229691) helps me to redesign my circuit and replace the gates by an integrated circuit.

However, a [second answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527960/229691) tickled my curiosity. It is said:

> You can wire up a multiplexer to act as any of the standard gate types (AND, OR, NOT, etc.) It's pretty easy to find a quad 2:1 multiplexer chip, and that one chip should be enough to implement all the logic you've shown.

I tried to redesign my circuit using 2:1 multiplexers:

[image: circuit with multiplexers]

The issue here is I'm using 2 different 2:1 multiplexers and I can't convert them into a 2 x 2:1 multiplexer. Indeed, the selector input is different for the two multiplexers and I'm not able to find a configuration with the same selector.

How can I redesign my circuit to use only one chip? Is there a method to convert logic gates to multiplexers?

Comment: You can find at least 3 of those muxes in a chip, so what's the problem?

Comment: @BrianDrummond The problem is I didn't know that. :) But I'm also curious to know how it is possible to build a circuit using a quad 2:1 multiplex chip.

Comment: Find a quad multiplexer then just use two of the multiplexers. Think about what your asking.

Comment: Instead of torturing your brain about it, simply make a **truth table** for a multiplexer. Then compare that to the truth table of an inverter, AND gate or OR gate. Note that if you connect one of the mux's inputs to zero or one you can get a behavior identical to a certain gate.

Comment: @Andyaka a quad MUX with independent Select inputs would need at least 18 pins : the classic 74xx157 has a common Select input which won't implement this answer. I was thinking about the 74HC4053; can you think of a suitable quad mux?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - is there a restriction on using no more than 16 pins I wonder?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes : the age of the "TTL Data Book" copy that's within reach!

Comment: To be honest, I'm totally new about multiplexer and I thought quad 2:1 mux had always only one common selector input. Apparently, you're telling me I was wrong. However, just by curiosity, is there a way to do what I want with this kind of multiplexer?

Comment: If you find one with independent inputs it'll be in a 20 pin package. I can't recall one offhand.

Comment: [ADG1634](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1633_1634.pdf).

Comment: @Andyaka Do you think the "break before make" behaviour of an analogue switch could leave a CMOS digital input unconnected long enough for that floating condition to be a problem? I had never considered the use of an analogue switch in a digital multiplexer role before. Interesting.

Comment: @SimonFitch sure it could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

74xx1G97 chips implement a single multiplexer. Their datasheets (e.g., [SN74LVC1G97](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/SN74LVC1G97/datasheet)) show how to wire it to implement your logic "NAND with one inverted input" with a single MUX:

> [image: SN74LVC1G97 MUX]
> Figure 3. 2-to-1 Data Selector
>
> [image: SN74LVC1G97 NAND]
> Figure 5. 2-Input NAND Gate With One Inverted Input

(There are five similar chips that allow different logic gates to be implemented: [SN74LVC1G57](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G57), [SN74LVC1G58](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G58),
[SN74LVC1G97](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G97),
[SN74LVC1G98](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G98),
[SN74LVC1G99](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G99).)

Answer (score 0):

So think of the truth table of a logic circuit, to know the output of the circuit you look up the value in the table corresponding to the input. The bits of the inputs gives you a number and you select from the table using that number as an index. This idea is called a look up table and is very common electronics hardware. And it physically is a multiplexer with its inputs wired up to all constants 1s and 0s. I have a part on my desk, xc7z010clg400, that has 17600 LUTs. They are 5 inputs, so each one is a multiplexer with 5 addr inputs, one output, and 32 programmable constant bits at the inputs to the multiplexer. They are used to acheive the same thing you are asking about, you're right to want to be able to use one general approach rather than need to pick between what kind of gate every time.

Now if you only have 2x1 multiplexers, you are going to need to start by building a bigger multiplexer then you can apply the LUT theory with that. Just always start off with 2^n-1 multiplexers for n inputs, connect them up in a binary tree, and then connect all the inputs to the values from the truth table.